# Is this usage of the verb "hold" correct?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

In a song I need to address the following request to mother nature and in particular to one of the four elements, water:

> Your waters hold your floods they're so deadly

Is this line correct and does it make the sense I'm expecting?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Your waters hold your floods, they're so deadly." Technically, you need a semicolon (;) between the two clauses, but since it's a song, I think you can get away with a comma as a stylistic choice (i.e., the pause required of a semicolon would be too pregnant for me personally).

Comment: And "hold" is fine for this lyric.

Comment: See how you like it with a hyphen instead of a comma or semicolon.

Comment: @Davo Hyphens (-) are used to create hyphenated phrases. You mean a **dash** (—).